# How do I configure Chrome to use the system installed Flash instead of the bundled one?

Tags: flash, google-chrome

I just updated to Chrome 20.0.1132.43 which includes Flash 11.3.31.109. Since that update most of the flash videos I watch online will randomly display erratic behavior (skipping like a broken CD, "fast forwarding" at twice the frame rate with the audio being scrambled due to too fast playback, restarting every video after two seconds, fullscreen overlay being displayed but no image, fullscreen taking several seconds to actually show a picture, youtube player to go fullscreen but then hang in the controls fadeout animation with no picture -sound keeps playing).

Is there anything I can do to resolve or work around this?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64Bit and the latest nvidia-current drivers 295.40 on a Geforce GT 440. It used to work in previous versions of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 14):

I disabled the internal flash at Chrome to fix this problem for the moment.

Type `about:plugins` in the URL Bar. Then click on "Details".
Disable the internal Flash plugin and use the plugin from the system (11.2)

Comment: I spent some time to figure out I need to click [+] in top right corner to see all details of each plugin. In this case 2 plugins from Flash section. Then remember to disable internal (paper) google flash plugin. :)

Answer (score 5):

@RipClaw had part of the answer (disable Flash Player 11.3), but my computer did not automatically start using the system's Flash Player.

The following is necessary to get Flash Player 11.2 working again in Chrome 20 (this worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04, anyway):

1. [download Flash Player 11.2](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) (for "Select version to download...." choose "API for Ubuntu 10.04+)
2. manually install the plugin

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /opt/google/chrome/plugins
   sudo cp /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins
   ```

Now if you visit `chrome://plugins` in your browser, you should see something like

```
Flash (4 files) - Version: 11.2 r202
Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
```