# Flash videos go haywire in fullscreen mode in Google Chrome 20

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, flash, google-chrome, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash player in Chrome 20?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157082/how-do-i-fix-flash-player-in-chrome-20)

Whenever I go fullscreen on a youtube video, there is a moment of static, then the controls continuously jump all over the screen, and it seems like the player is trying to center the video between both monitors (I have a two monitor system).

Never had any problems watching full screen flash videos with my dual monitor setup (same hardware) in 11.10 or 10.04. This problem **only began after upgrading to 12.04**.

Here is a screenshot (showing both monitors, fullscreen video on the left):
(not enough reputation to embed... lame) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj5YM.png

No other graphics problems on any other applications. Videos display fullscreen in firefox as expected (HTML 5 instead of flash?)

Here is some flash debug info, not sure if it's useful:

`ts=1340905046&stacktrace=&cl=31482712&debug%5FsourceData=B3D5B0986HH1341141813925019&videoFps=26&debug%5Fdate=Sun%20Jul%201%2018%3A23%3A59%20GMT%2B0700%202012&debug%5FplaybackQuality=hd720&debug%5FvideoId=9I8cVlZDOT4&droppedFrames=345&stageFps=10&debug%5FflashVersion=LNX%2011%2C3%2C31%2C109`

I've tried re-installing chrome with no success.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT** - I removed '12.04' from the title as this is a chrome / flash issue and not a problem with 12.04. See comment below for the fix (can't answer for 8 hours).

Comment: The answer provided here worked for me (didn't find it in my first search attempts). 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/157082/how-do-i-fix-flash-player-in-chrome-20

Essentially: 

 - Type about:plugins in the URL bar
 - Click details
 - Disable flash (11.3)
 - Chrome will default to system plugin (11.2)

This isn't a fix, it's a roll back to a version that works... but at least everything behaves as expected again.