# Adobe flash playing at double speed, studders on Firefox, Chromium, Chrome

Tags: flash, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

[this question seems very similar to mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157082/how-do-i-fix-flash-player-in-chrome-20)

Maybe I'm the first one and perhaps this can serve as a place for everyone to get the fix

Chromium: 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Flash: 11,2,202,236 installed

It studders or it plays double the speed

Same experience in Firefox 13.0.1

also in Chrome: 20.0.1132.47

```
lspci:

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 01)
07:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
```

Comment: Install Google chrome(Remove Chromium). Update Flash.

Comment: Could be a problem with the sound system. Any other problems with sound recording or playback?

Comment: Audio is fine (listening to podcast through Rhythmbox now). Unlike the most recent issue linked to, I am having issues at atleast vimeo.com and blip.tv. As far as using a new browser? That's sort of like saying reinstall with fedora. But thanks all so far, in all honesty I just expect that this will be a waiting game till the next update, but I will certainly be watching this thread. I just threw this up cause these are standard enough apps I suspect a bunch of others are getting hit too.

Comment: Temporary Fix: install and run pavucontrol, went to the configuration tab, and turned my sound devices off then back on.

Comment: @DavidA maybe running `pulseaudio -k` will also work as temporary fix. Pulseaudio will get killed, but it will restart itself automatically.